# Install Jhipster with node js

Tags: java, node.js, jhipster

I installed Java 10 and node.js on my PC. Then I installed jhipster with the command:

```
npm install - g generator-jhipster
```

After I run the jhipster command to create my project, its tells me jhipster is not a recognized Windows command. I just don’t understand why.

Comment: try to use the node console

Comment: I use the cmd console

Comment: please try to use the node console if it will works fine so all you have is to manage your path vars

Comment: I am the same result

Comment: Is it necessary to install Yarn?

Comment: no as long as you have npm

Comment: for node use an LTS version please

Comment: I'm version 10.11

Comment: Your command has an extra space in `- g` rather than the expected `-g`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo need to check where is jhipster installed on your machine and maybe change your PATH variable so it points correctly to the tool install.

Remember to reopen the command line to take effect.

Comment: How I can check or is installed jhipster. This is a node module